# Transformation of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability

If $X \sim U(0,a)$, what's the pdf of $e^{2X}$ ? Is it also $U(0,a)$ ? Or perhaps one has to integrate $e^{2X}$ to get a normalizing constant?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  The language is loose but can be cleaned up.

Comment: For $ t > 0 $ , $$P( \exp 2X \leq t ) = P( X \leq \frac{\ln t}{2} ) $$

Comment: hint: $P(Y\leq y)=P(e^{2X}\leq y)=P(X \leq \frac{\ln y}{2})$

Comment: "Is it also $U(0,a)$?" Have you tried working out _what_ values $e^{2X}$ can take on? What value of $X$ will give you $Y = e^{2X} = 0.1$, say?

Comment: @rlgordonma _My_ downvote (it is not the only one) is because the OP seems not to have put in _any_ effort into even _thinking_ about the question before posting it.

Comment: @rlgordonma Furthermore, reading any one of a number of quite similar previous questions would yield an easy method to solve this one.